# How to lock orientation in UINavigationControllers

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, orientation, ios6

As the `ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is deprecated in **iOS 6** I am not able to lock the orientation in my app. In my app I have `UINavigationControllers` with multiple views, some views need to support both portrait and landscape, while other views need to support portrait only. How can I over come this problem please suggest me some idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use this function only work in **iOS 6**

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation

{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

}
```

Comment: see my updated answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933089/i-want-to-make-my-appliaction-only-in-landscape-orientation-in-ios-both-ios-5-a

Answer (score 2):

You lock the orientation by subclassing UINavigationController.

[Here is an excellent link on how to do that.](https://gist.github.com/lessthanyouthink/3842178)

Then you override the following methods in your subclassed UIViewController to achieve the lock (in this case a portrait lock).

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely no effect what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in viewDidLoad

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

For locking portrait orientation

- Select attribute inspector tab.
- Set orientation into portrait.

Add the function

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)); 
}
```

For locking landscape orientation

- Select attribute inspector tab.
- Set orientation into landscape.

Add the function

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation) ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the alternate for ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation.I will like to suggest you to go through these links -

http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2012/09/21/ios6-autorotation-changes

Thanks