# RealityKit – Create line between two points in 3d space

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

**How to create a line between two points in 3d space with RealityKit?**

There are examples of [creating lines between two points in Scenekit](https://www.iditect.com/how-to/58470229.html), however, there are basically none using RealityKit.

To create the line, I've created a rectangle model entity and placed it between my first touched point and the current touched point. From here, all I would need to do is rotate the rectangle to face the current touched point. However, using the `simd_quatf(from: to:)` doesn't work as intended.

```
rectangleModelEntity.transform.rotation = simd_quatf(from: firstTouchedPoint, 
                                                       to: currTouchedPoint)
```

If I were to touch a point and then drag directly downwards, the rectangle model should be to be a straight line between first touched and current touched point, but it stays horizontal with a slight tilt.

To solve this, I tried getting the angle between my initially horzontal line as a vector and a vector from the first touched to current touched point

```
let startVec = currTouchedPoint - firstTouchedPoint
let endVec = endOfModelEntityPoint - modelEntityCenterPoint
let lengthVec = simd_length(cross(startVec, endVec))
        
let theta = atan2(lengthVec, dot(startVec, endVec))
```

This gives me the angle between two vectors in 3d space, which seems correct, when I checked it gave me 90 degrees when touching and dragging directly between it.

The problem is I don't know what the axis to rotate it on should be. Since this is 3d space, the line doesn't need to be on a 2d plane, the current touched position can be downwards and in front of the starting touch position.

```
rectangleModelEntity = simd_quatf(angle: theta, axis: ???)
```

Personally, I'm not even too sure if the above is the correct solution to creating a line between two points. In theory it's rather basic, create a rectangle with low height/depth to mimic a line, position it in the center of the starting and current touch point then rotate it so it's oriented correctly.

**What should be the axis for the above degrees between two vectors?**

**Is there a better method of creating two lines between points in 3d space with RealityKit/ARKit?**

Answer (score 4):

I have implemented using a box. Let me know if you have a better way.

```
 let midPosition = SIMD3(x:(position1.x + position2.x) / 2,
                            y:(position1.y + position2.y) / 2,
                            z:(position1.z + position2.z) / 2)
    
    let anchor = AnchorEntity()
    anchor.position = midPosition
    anchor.look(at: position1, from: midPosition, relativeTo: nil)
    
    let meters = simd_distance(position1, position2)
    
    let lineMaterial = SimpleMaterial.init(color: .red,
                                           roughness: 1,
                                           isMetallic: false)
    
    let bottomLineMesh = MeshResource.generateBox(width:0.025,
                                                  height: 0.025/2.5,
                                                  depth: meters)
    
    let bottomLineEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: bottomLineMesh,
                                       materials: [lineMaterial])
    
    bottomLineEntity.position = .init(0, 0.025, 0)
    anchor.addChild(bottomLineEntity)
```

Answer (score 0):

The axis is the cross product of the direction your object is facing at the beginning and the direction it should be facing now.
Like if it's at position `p1=[x1,y1,z1]`, initially facing d1=[0, 0, -1], and you want it to face a point `p2=[x, y, z]` the axis would be the cross product: `|d1|✕|p2 - p1|`.

May have to swap the two around, or just negate the angle though, depending on how it works out.

Comment: By the direction the object is facing, if my line is on a vertical surface would the direction be [0, 1, 0]. Where y = 1 indicates the direction is straight outwards? Although, it seems like z = 1 based on this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59671828/what-is-the-orientation-of-arkits-camera-space



Or does this mean the direction of the line object, since it starts off horizontally, that would be a vector from the position of the object to the right end of the line object.

Comment: Yes straight up is [0, 1, 0]. Calculate the product of that and the direction you want it to face, [0, 0, 1]. The result is [1, 0, 0], this is the axis used by the quaternion.