# UIinterface orientation ios6

Tags: ios, ios6

My code is working fine in **iOS 5.1** but not in **iOS 6**. I am getting orientation problems.

I am using this code for controlling the orientations

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;

}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

I want to show one view controller in Landscape mode and other viewController in Portrait mode

Any one can help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600778/how-to-lock-orientation-in-uinavigationcontrollers/12601324#12601324

Comment: i think you have to override this method:  - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window

Comment: and see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933089/i-want-to-make-my-appliaction-only-in-landscape-orientation-in-ios-both-ios-5-a

Answer (score 1):

Try look at this

[iOS 6 Tips and Tricks Upgrading Your Apps](http://grembe.wordpress.com/2012/09/19/here-is-what-i/)

**OR**

try to add this codes in Main viewcontroller:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {

return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;

}

- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)w {

return (NSUInteger)[application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:w] | (1<<UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);

}
```

And main viewcontroller must be added how:

```
[window setRootViewController: mainController];
```

instead

```
[window addSubview: mainController.view];
```

Comment: Link only answers are not welcome at so. Please add some more detail to your answer.